# Rails :text_area with tool box

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, textarea

I want to design a text_area with toolbox in rails. Is there any way or gem to do that? [image]

Comment: down voters please comment the reason here.

Comment: @pojaAgarwal You are not having a problem - you are asking for someone to do the job for you, because you are not capable to do it yourself. Provide what you have tried and someone might help you with a specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved that through tinymce-rails gem.